# Got JSON parse error at @RequestBody if using HttpServerRequestWrapper

Tags: spring-boot, encoding

I'm posting httprequest to a spring boot restful server. the ContentType is "application/json;charset=UTF-8".

I wrote a filter to wrap the HttpServletRequest:

```
public class WebRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private final String body;

    public WebRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("Error reading the request body...");
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    logger.error("Error closing bufferedReader...");
                }
            }
        }

        body = stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        final StringReader reader = new StringReader(body);
        ServletInputStream inputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
            @Override
            public boolean isFinished() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isReady() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {

            }

            public int read() throws IOException {
                return reader.read();
            }
        };
        return inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

My controller looks like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/CustomerRegister")
public RegisterResponse register(@Validated @RequestBody RegisterRequest request) {
    log.info("customer register request start! request=[{}]", request);
    RegisterResponse response = new RegisterResponse(request.getBussSeqNo(), request.getSysSeqNo());
    return response;
}
```

Everything is ok when the request body contains english alphabet.
But if the request body contains Chinese characters.The server will throw exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3de12d42; line: 4, column: 14]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3de12d42; line: 4, column: 14]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3de12d42; line: 4, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.ktjr.ktwd.customer.domain.openapi.RegisterRequest["name"])
```

Any hint is welcomed.

Comment: What's the point of this `WebRequestWrapper `?

Comment: I wrote a `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` to getInputStream of the request body. Because request can be consumed only once, So I have to write a wrapper request to store the original request.   @Ali Dehghani